# If statement runs again after the condition is changed to not valid one.C# / Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with if statement that runs 1 more time after i change the condition at the end to one that's not valid. I need it to stop after i changed the condition not loop 1 more time. Here is the code, look at **if (Direction == "R")**   ///  if (Direction == "S") has almost the same code(Changes only in variables/names that i removed from the code so its easy to see what i have problem with) and it works fine. Thanks.

```
void Update()
{
    
}
IEnumerator spawnTile()
{

    if (Direction == "S") 
    {   
        //Deleted code
    }

    if (Direction == "L") 
    {
        //Deleted code
    }

    if (Direction == "R")         //WHY THIS RUNS after Direction has been changed to "S" ??
    {

        if (Rotated == "R")                              
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("R");
            nextTileSpawn.x += 6f;
            nextTileSpawn.z -= 6.5f;
            Instantiate(tileObj, nextTileSpawn, tileObj.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0));  
            nextTileSpawn.x += 10;
            Rotated = "yes";
        }


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);


        if (nextTileSpawn.x > startTurnR)                                          
        {
            startTurnR += 500;
          
          System.Random random = new System.Random();
          randomz = random.Next((startTurnR - 450) / 10 + 1, (startTurnR - 10) / 10 + 1) * 10 -2.5f ;          

        }

        if (nextTileSpawn.x == randomz)
        {
            nextTurnTileSpawn.x = randomz;
            Instantiate(turnTileObj, nextTurnTileSpawn, turnTileObj.rotation);

                Rotated = "S";                        
                Direction = "S";
        }
        StartCoroutine(spawnTile());
 
    }
    
}`
```

Comment: To start a coroutine inside a coroutine u need:`yield return StartCoroutine(spawnTile());`

Comment: I wanted to go back to the first coroutine not start another one inside it, the problem is that after changing the Direction to "S"   The statement: if (Direction == "R") runs 1 more time and then goes to  if (Direction == "S") . After direction change i want it directly to go to  if (Direction == "S") .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use else if if u want to run just 1 times.

Comment: This worked thanks, not sure why runs 1 more time only with if

Comment: with the if block will always return true or false. if u have 5 if block they will always run. But  if u use if-elseIf-else block if one condition true other conditions will not run.